# Name error: name 'url_feed" is not defined. is a variable's type not defined?

Tags: python

here is the code that i use it several times without any error. i hadn't defined any type of variable for 'url-feed' but there were no error. but now i have this.

```
def update_channels(feed_id, temperature, humidity, lux):
    url_feed = url + '/v2/feeds/' + str(feed_id) + '.json'
    headers = {'X-ApiKey': str(MASTER_API_KEY)}
```

Comment: Does the traceback show that the error is for line `url_feed = url + '/v2/feeds/' + str(feed_id) + '.json'` ?

Comment: in fact it was a "connection failed" error. i put the exception and then i encountered with that error. whatever i didn't use 'url_feed' anyplace except this: try:
                r = requests.put(url=url_feed, headers=headers, data=payload)